# A transitive closure axiom for a machine operating system.

Tags: soft-question, computer-science, computability, computational-mathematics, axioms

The following section is pure speculation on my part, but I feel compelled to share it on the math stackexchange. I used tags on this question to draw in experts, not to imply any knowledge I have in these areas.

---

In set theory, understanding the definition of [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) involves the acceptance of an underlying construction that can involve an infinite number of recursive steps. It is also of interest that finite sets can be defined by

Definition: A set $X$ is said to be finite if there exists a binary relation $\rho$ on $X$ satisfying the following two properties:

$\tag 1 \rho \text{ is a bijective correspondence on }X$
$\tag 2 \text{The transitive closure of } \rho \text{ is equal to } X \times X$

But with a 'stripped down' set theory that a machine can work with, the transitive closure can be 'programmed' as an axiom:

AoTC: Given a binary relation $R$ on a set X there exists a binary relation $\hat R$ satisfying the following two properties,

$\;$ The relation $\hat R$ is transitive and $R \subset \hat R$.
$\;$ If $T$ is a transitive relation and $R \subset T$ then $\hat R \subset T$.

> Have axioms every been 'designed' for use by a computing operating system?

Comment: Of interest here, - I did a duckduckgo search and found; $\quad$ [The impact of transitive closure on the expressiveness of navigational query languages on unlabeled graphs](https://research.tue.nl/nl/publications/the-impact-of-transitive-closure-on-the-expressiveness-of-navigat)  $\quad$ [A Transitive Model For Artificial Intelligence Applications](https://www.deepdyve.com/lp/spie/a-transitive-model-for-artificial-intelligence-applications-vRx4IVHIK7)

Comment: "a 'stripped down' set theory that a machine can work with" What exactly do you mean by this? (Either part, really: what set theory do you have in mind, and what are your criteria for machine-usable?) As to the mathematics, you might look into **least fixed point** logics. Their behavior on *finite* structures is relevant to complexity theory, for example.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The question was meant to be loose and open, but your question drove me to find [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit#Complex_operations) as a 'FYI link'. In my vision I can see ALU's evolving and incorporating math logic/theory in gulps (axioms). It might also be interesting for the computer to show independent thought - [My mind is going. I can feel it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-La91wr8xw)

Comment: @NoahSchweber Found this on cstheory stackexchange: [Understanding least-fixed point logic](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/14202). These 'points' can be the answer to real world questions.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this after thinking about Noah's comment in an attempt to actualize (physicality is the motivation) the specific AoTC axiom I used in my question.

Here I am going to sketch a $\text{2 by 2 TC chip}$ design.

Inputs: $4$ on/off Pins, so $2^4$ signals,  one for each vertex in the $\text{2 by 2 TC chip}$.

Black Box: Take the transitive closure of the the vertices that are turned on by the input pins.

Outputs: $2$ on/off Pins:

$\quad$ Pin 1: On if any vertex in on.

$\quad$ Pin 2: On if any vertex on the diagonal is on.

This chip can handle the logical binary operations of conjunction, disjunction, and XOR.

---

This is a fun *imagination puzzle* to work on and I don't want to spoil that by putting up all the details.